# Crashlytics upload symbols- "java command failed with args" -how fix it?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, macos, crashlytics

I have flutter app. I working on mac. I used obfuscation for my appbundle. I get logs for Crashlytics in unreadable form. I found that it is necessary to load symbols on Crashlytics(Firebase).
I installed Firebase cli and got my app id. I run it command:

```
firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app myId debug-info/app.android-arm64.symbols
```

But I have error, This is logs:

```
i  Generating symbols for debug-info-droid/app.android-arm64.symbols
i  Generated symbols for debug-info-droid/app.android-arm64.symbols
.......
i  Uploading all generated symbols...
[CRASHLYTICS LOG DEBUG] PUT headers:
[CRASHLYTICS LOG DEBUG]         User-Agent = firebase-cli;crashlytics-buildtools/2.9.2
[CRASHLYTICS LOG DEBUG]         X-CRASHLYTICS-API-CLIENT-TYPE = firebase-cli;crashlytics-buildtools
[CRASHLYTICS LOG DEBUG]         X-CRASHLYTICS-API-CLIENT-VERSION = 2.9.2
[CRASHLYTICS LOG DEBUG] PUT response: [reqId=null] 400
......
response: 400 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.api.RestfulWebApi.sendFile(RestfulWebApi.java:109)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.api.RestfulWebApi.uploadFile(RestfulWebApi.java:119)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.api.FirebaseSymbolFileService.uploadNativeSymbolFile(FirebaseSymbolFileService.java:35)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools.uploadNativeSymbolFiles(Buildtools.java:301)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.CommandLineHelper.executeUploadSymbols(CommandLineHelper.java:194)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.CommandLineHelper.executeCommand(CommandLineHelper.java:120)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.CommandLineHelper.main(CommandLineHelper.java:65)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools.main(Buildtools.java:111)
Error: java command failed with args: -jar,/Users/rockstar/.cache/firebase/crashlytics/buildtools/crashlytics-buildtools-2.9.2.jar,-symbolGenerator,breakpad,-symbolFileCacheDir,/var/folders/jg/../nativeSymbols/.../breakpad,-verbose,-uploadNativeSymbols,-googleAppId,myId,-clientName,
firebase-cli;crashlytics-buildtools
```

how can i fix this problem?

is it related to java settings on my mac?

maybe i can use another solution to uploading symbols?

Comment: Have you looked at this https://medium.com/@farshadmb/upload-dsym-file-automatically-into-firebase-crashlytics-for-ios-253439165bab haven't yet tried it myself.

Comment: It if about iOS, my issue "for Android"

Comment: Yeah apologies... should have read this question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also spent weeks on that!

As per https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=flutter#add-sdk, the command is:

```
firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app=APP_ID PATH/TO/symbols
```

It seems the `APP_ID` you provided is malformed, so you get a "[reqId=null] error".

Do not use your app id formatted like "com.myflutterapp".

Find your app_id in the Firebase console's project settings page.

The "app id" should be the one formatted like `1:xxxxx:android:xxxxabc...`.

[image: Firebase console's project settings page]

Do not forget to upload the symbols for both Android and iOS apps, respectively replacing their APP_IDs.

Moreover, keep always your deobfuscation symbols organized by build number. If not, "you'll do nothing" uploading the symbols from a build expecting to deobfuscate other build's Crashlytics logs.

The Firebase crashlytics logs always show which build id that's related for. Example:

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: Null check operator used on a null value. Error thrown Instance of 'CD'.
BuildId: tyb30glke21t763gs87gbbz9dvvs69869vs6
```

When you upload the symbols, the build id appears in the debug logs so you can check it is being uploading for the right build.

Answer (score 1):

As a sidenote: "Error: java command failed with args: [...]" with the detail "An unknown error occurred" can also result from simply not having java installed or the PATH not being correctly set up.

Check for this with the command "java -version"